# Using Beautiful Soup to scrape a url in a css class?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This is the the html I can scrape with the following code. I'm just trying to get the link from it. driver is for selenium.

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

file_link = soup.select(".inpfilelink")
return file_link

print file_upload("/home/ro/Documents/Aaatrack.pdf")
```

The html I'm trying to scrape.

```
<input class="inpfilelink" type="text" onclick="window.open(this.value);" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px; font-size: 13px;" onmouseover="this.focus(); this.select()" value="http://speedy.sh/PFZwD/offsore.pdf" title="Press CTRL + C to copy to clipboard now">
```

I've also tried

```
link = soup.find('input')['value']
print(link)
```

which returns
      markup_type=markup_type))

```
/upload_page.php
```

I've also tried just doing

```
link = soup.find('input')
```

which returns

```
<input name="redir" type="hidden" value="/upload_page.php"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to scrape the url from the `value` in `input`:

```
link = soup.find('input')['value']
print(link)
```

**Result**:

```
http://speedy.sh/PFZwD/offsore.pdf
```

Scrape any of the properties by using them within `['...']`

Comment: Maybe try using `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')` and see if there's any difference.

Comment: yeah I've tried both "lxml" and "xml" both return without any errors